# Pasar una lista a cadena de texto sin .join

Tags: python, numpy

quería saber si existe alguna forma de pasar una lista numérica de numpy a una cadena para trabajar con ella SIN usar el método join.

Por ejemplo, la lista [11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99] pasarla a una cadena de texto (o generar una cadena de texto nueva en base a la lista) de la siguiente forma ("11","22","33",...,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo del todo la pregunta pero, ¿hay algún problema en recorrer la lista e ir añadiendo elementos a un string iniciamente vacío?

```
import numpy as np
lista = np.array([11, 22, 33, 44])
cadena = ""
for elemento in lista:
    cadena += "'%s', " % str(elemento)

print(cadena) # "'11', '22', '33', '44', "
```

Teniendo esto, todo es refinar el código para añadir paréntesis al inicio y final de la cadena, o evitar la coma del último elemento, pero creo que eso es trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pones como ejemplo del resultado buscado no es una cadena de texto, sino una tupla cuyos elementos son cadenas.

Esto puedes lograrlo así:

```
lista = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99]
resultado = tuple(str(x) for x in lista)
```

lo que deja en `resultado` la siguiente tupla (repito, no es una cadena):

```
('11', '22', '33', '44', '55', '66', '77', '88', '99')
```

Si lo que querías por el contrario era pasar la lista entera a cadena, es algo tan sencillo como `str(lista)` lo que produce la cadena:

```
'[11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99]'
```

O si lo que querías es algo como la tupla que antes mostré, pero que en vez de tupla sea cadena, puedes hacer `str(resultado)` sobre mi solución inicial, lo que producirá la cadena:

```
"('11', '22', '33', '44', '55', '66', '77', '88', '99')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Viendo lo que buscas como respuesta, es una tupla, en ese caso esto te puede servir:

```py
mi_lista = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99]
mi_tupla = tuple(mi_lista)

print(mi_tupla)  # (11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99)
```

Ahora bien si lo que necesitas es una string:

```py
mi_lista = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99]
mi_str = str(mi_lista).replace("[", "").replace("]", "")

print(mi_str)  # 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99
```